# .Net Standard 2.0 with Realm 3.4.0 'could not resolve reference' Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I have created new Xamarin.Forms project with Android and iOS. After that I  installed *Realm(3.4.0)* in my all 3 projects(PCL, Android and iOS) using nuget. I have also manually added FodyWeavers.xml and I am getting below warning:

> could not resolve reference "packages\realm\3.4.0\build..\native\ios\universal\librealm-wrappers.a". if this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

When I am checking for this file at the specified path, file exists in my system.

Comment: In your question title, you said .Net standard and later on you said you are using PCL's so what exactly are you using?

Comment: If you are using last Xamarin tempaltes with .net standard, you don't need anymore to add the nuget package to all your projects

Comment: @G.hakim By PCL I meant to say the shared project. I have used .netstandard2.0 only.

Comment: @OrcusZ, I have added Realm package using nuget package manager

Comment: @Daxa Varsani A .Net standard and a PCL is different my friend and .Net Standards are called SCL's FYI, `By PCL I meant to say the shared project` [Shared projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects) are actually a different type of Xamarin.Forms Project.

Comment: Also after reading the error thoroughly notice that this must be a `Warning` and not an `Error` or is it an error?

Comment: @G.hakim I completely agree with you PCL and .netstandard is different. Yes I am getting warning not an error, as I mentioned in my question description.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the Nuget and reinstalling it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187647/discussion-between-daxa-varsani-and-g-hakim).

Answer (score 0):

For me it's solved by delleting folders bin, obj(Image below) and closing the Visual Studio, after just rebuild it and everithing ok.
 Hope it helps.[image]